# Uploading Stream to Database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have a `FileForUploading` class which should be uploaded to a database.

```
public class FileForUploading
{
    public FileForUploading(string filename, Stream stream)
    {
        this.Filename = filename;
        this.Stream = stream;
    }

    public string Filename { get; private set; }

    public Stream Stream { get; private set; }
}
```

I am using the Entity Framework to convert it to a `FileForUploadingEntity`
which is a very simple class  that however only contains the `Filename` property. I don't want to store the `Stream` in memory but rather upload it directly to the database.

What would be the best way to 'stream' the `Stream` directly to the database?

So far I have come up with this

```
private void UploadStream(string name, Stream stream)
    {
        var sqlQuery = @"UPDATE dbo.FilesForUpload SET Content =@content WHERE Name=@name;";

        var nameParameter = new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@name",
            Value = name
        };

        var contentParameter = new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@content",
            Value = ConvertStream(stream),
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Binary
        };

        // the database context used throughout the application.
        this.context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlQuery, contentParameter, nameParameter);
    }
```

And here is my `ConvertStream` which converts the `Stream` to a `byte[]`. (It is stored as a `varbinary(MAX)` in the database.

```
private static byte[] ConvertStream(Stream stream)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Is the above solution good enough? Will it perform well if the `Stream` is large?

Comment: With the above solution you proposed you still have the content of the stream in memory in your application which you mentioned initially is something you were trying to avoid. `I don't want to store the Stream in memory but rather upload it directly to the database.`

Comment: Could you be a little more specific as to why this is the case? So then I know what would have to changed.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot do a streaming `UPDATE` only a streaming `INSERT` or it's equivalent.  SQLBulkCopy() is one way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't want to store the Stream in memory but rather upload it directly to the database.

With the above solution you proposed you still have the content of the stream in memory in your application which you mentioned initially is something you were trying to avoid.

Your best bet is to go around EF and use the async function to upload the stream. The following example is taken from [MSDN article SqlClient Streaming Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556234(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
// Application transferring a large BLOB to SQL Server in .Net 4.5
private static async Task StreamBLOBToServer() {

 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    await conn.OpenAsync();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [BinaryStreams] (bindata) VALUES (@bindata)", conn)) {
       using (FileStream file = File.Open("binarydata.bin", FileMode.Open)) {

          // Add a parameter which uses the FileStream we just opened
          // Size is set to -1 to indicate "MAX"
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@bindata", SqlDbType.Binary, -1).Value = file;

          // Send the data to the server asynchronously
          await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
       }
    }
 }
}
```

You could convert this sample to the following to make it work for you. Note that you should change the signature on your method to make it async so you can take advantage of not having a thread blocked during a long lasting database update.

```
// change your signature to async so the thread can be released during the database update/insert act
private async Task UploadStreamAsync(string name, Stream stream) {

    var conn = this.context.Database.Connection; // SqlConnection from your DbContext
    if(conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        await conn.OpenAsync();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.FilesForUpload SET Content =@content WHERE Name=@name;", conn)) {
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(){ParameterName = "@name",Value = name});
          // Size is set to -1 to indicate "MAX"
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@content", SqlDbType.Binary, -1).Value = stream;
          // Send the data to the server asynchronously
          await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

---

One more note. If you want to save large unstructured data sets (ie. the Streams you are getting uploaded) then it might be a better idea to not save them in the database. There are numerous reasons why but foremost is that relational database were not really designed with this in mind, its cumbersome to work with the data, and they can chew up database space real fast making other operations more difficult (ie. backups, restores, etc).

There is an alternative that still natively allows you to save a pointer in the record but have the actual unstructured data reside on disk. You can do this using the [Sql Server FileStream](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx). In ADO.NET you would be working with [SqlFileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream(v=vs.110).aspx). Here is a good walk through on how to configure your Sql Server and database to allow for Sql File Streams. It also has some Vb.net examples on how to use the `SqlFileStream` class.

[An Introduction to SQL Server FileStream](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/)

---

*I did assume you were using Microsoft Sql Server as your data repository. If this assumption is not correct please update your question and also add a tag for the correct database service you are connecting to.*

Comment: While this is streaming within the client program it is *not* streaming on the SQL Server side, but rather relies on incremental execution of SQL commands and thus will be fairly slow.  `SQLBulkCopy()` is (one of) the preferred approaches for large datasets and will typically be 10x-100x faster.